# pipe the read command?

Tags: bash, read

I'm trying to pipe a string with special characters (e.g. `HG@eg3,l'{TT\"C!` to another command ([termux-clipboard-set](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-clipboard-set)) with the `read` program. It seems that `read` was designed to create a temporary variable (e.g. `read temp`) that should be then passed to another command (e.g. `termux-clipboard-set $temp`).

I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do it with a pipe, like: `read | termux-clipboard-set`?

UPDATE: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm looking for something that would work on bash (termux).

Comment: Why do you want to use `read` here? Also, what shell are you using and what operating system? Does your shell support something like `termux-clipboard-set <<<"HG@eg3,l'{TT\"C!"`?

Comment: 1. Thanks, I've updated the tag to bash. I didn't expect it to play such a big role. 2. Because this string is usually much longer (I've truncated it in the example) and you'd need to manually go and escape every quote and other special characters.

Comment: Then please mention this in your question. Basically, please explain what you want to achieve rather than focusing on the method you think might achieve it. This is what is known as the [xy probem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). `read` isn't  the right tool here, so focusing on how to force `read` to work is distracting from the basic question which seems to be "how can I pass a long string with special characters to the termux-clipboard-set command?".

Comment: Where does your string with special characters come from? Are you reading it from a file, or is it the output of some command? Anyway, I think you don't want to use `read` or a pipe. I have several rules for using bash, and one is keep things simple and go one step at a time, and another is don't use `read` except for user interaction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For `bash`, `read` is not a program. `read` is a builtin. Simplified, `read` reads `stdin` and assigns that input to a variable. The `read` builtin does not produce any output on `stdout`, so trying to pipe `stdout` to something does not produce anything.

The question is why.  According to the `man` page,

> Usage `termux-clipboard-set [text]`
>
> Text is read either from standard input or from command line arguments.

If text is read from `stdin`, why would you want to put something in front? Sure, you could `cat | termux-clipboard-set`, but just `termux-clipboard-set` would do the trick.

Comment: Oh, that explains why I couldn't redirect the output. I thought it was a regular program. Are there perhaps any alternatives that behave similarly but could be redirected?

Comment: @DanielKrajnik you can redirect the output of shell builtins just fine. You cannot redirect the output of `read` because it has no output, not because it is a builtin. `echo` is also a builtin on most shells but its output can be redirected just fine.

Comment: thanks, I misunderstood it then. You are right in the last paragraph `cat | termux-clipboard-set` works (I couldn't find which key terminates cat - found out eventually that CTRL+D works). I don't think that just `termux-clipboard-set` works anymore (this [issue](https://github.com/termux/termux-api/issues/8#issuecomment-343729123) also mentions that it just hangs after pressing CTRL+D)

Comment: `cat` does nothing but copy bytes from its input to its output. So `cat | termux-clipboard-set` and `termux-clipboard-set` should behave 100% identically. If you're really finding that they're not, that's probably a quite subtle bug.

Answer (score 4):

In `zsh`, where the `read` builtin supports a `-e` option for `e`cho:

```
termux-clipboard-set "$(IFS= read -re)"
```

If your system still has a `line` command (there's still one in `util-linux` but it's generally not included these days), with any POSIX-like shell:

```
termux-clipboard-set "$(line)"
```

That `line` command could be written as a sh function as:

```
line() (
  IFS= read -r line; ret=$?
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
  exit "$ret"
)
```

`head -n 1` does something similar except that when not reading from a terminal most implementations would read by blocks¹ and then may read more than a line from their input even if they output only one line. `read` and `line` are guaranteed not to (though you need to make sure to use the `-r` option for `read`).

With input coming from a terminal,

```
termux-clipboard-set "$(head -n1)"
```

Should work though. Most `head` implementations still also support the obsolete (but shorter) `head -1`.

With tcsh, that's:

```
termux-clipboard-set $<:q
```

---

<sup>¹ they also read by blocks from terminal devices, but `read()`s on terminal devices in `icanon` mode don't return more than one line.</sup>

Comment: What is `line`? On my system it seems to be part of the `mesa-demos` package and running opens a window with a blue background and a triangle, while the terminal shows me the values of some `GL_*` variables.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately this time zsh isn't available :( (runs on termux android phone uses bash).

Comment: @terdon, `line` used to be a standard command up to SUSv2, removed thereafter and from many systems.